# React-admin giving error "Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child."

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am trying to implement the react-admin module. Going through the 30 minute tutorial which they have on the webpage. But it keeps erroring out with this error message

```
Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.
```

I am following the tutorial step by step so the code is similar as to what is available on their home page.

Here is my app component

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Admin, Resource } from 'react-admin';
import { PostList } from './posts';
import jsonServerProvider from 'ra-data-json-server';
import { UserList } from './users';

const dataProvider = jsonServerProvider('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com');

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
            <Resource name="posts" list={PostList} />   
            <Resource name="users" list={UserList} />    
        </Admin>
    )
}


export default App;
```

When I spun up create-react-app it had React.Strictmode in the index component. I read somewhere that this could be an issue, so I removed the strict mode and my Index component now looks like this

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

This is how my other posts component looks like

```
import * as React from "react";
import {
    List,
    Datagrid,
    TextField,
    ReferenceField,
    EditButton,
    Edit,
    Create,
    SimpleForm,
    ReferenceInput,
    SelectInput,
    TextInput,
} from 'react-admin';

export const PostList = props => (
    <div>
        <List {...props}>
+       <Datagrid>
+           <TextField source="id" />
            <ReferenceField source="userId" reference="users">
                <TextField source="name" />
            </ReferenceField>
-           <TextField source="id" />
            <TextField source="title" />
-           <TextField source="body" />
+           <EditButton />
        </Datagrid>
    </List> 
    </div>   
    )


    export const PostEdit = props => (
        <Edit {...props}>
            <SimpleForm>
                <TextInput disabled source="id" />
                <ReferenceInput source="userId" reference="users">
                     <SelectInput optionText="name" />
                </ReferenceInput>
                <TextInput source="title" />
                <TextInput multiline source="body" />
            </SimpleForm>
        </Edit>
    );

  export const PostCreate = props => (
        <Create {...props}>
            <SimpleForm>
                <ReferenceInput source="userId" reference="users">
                    <SelectInput optionText="name" />
                </ReferenceInput>
                <TextInput source="title" />
                <TextInput multiline source="body" />
            </SimpleForm>
        </Create>
    );
```

Comment: Apparently your problem is in other files, everything is fine with these.

Comment: i have updated the question with the other component..any tips?

Comment: In the PostList <div> is definitely superfluous, try commenting on your components one by one until the error disappears.

Comment: Can you show us what the User components look like?

Comment: i figured it out guys...thanks :)